# Xamarin WebView App (Hybrid) with Xamarin Essential

Tags: xamarin, webview, xamarin.android, android-webview

Sorry if this question is a bit basic in nature. I understand Xamarin Essential provides low-level device API (battery, gps, accelerometer, Camera, Call etc). Is it possible to build an Html based application using WebView that can leverage/access Xamarin essential API's?

In other words, use Xamarin essential API to read the values and display it in HTML?

Comment: Have you checked https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview ?

Comment: @SushiHangover Thanks for wonderful pointer, this is what I'm looking for. Could you please add this as an answer for this question? I will make it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @VenkateshMuniyandi The top web search will lead you to using Razor templates:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/platform/razor-html-templates/ or the "Call C# from JavaScript" link in the Android WebView doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/controls/web-view